# Why does the array_push() "deepen" the depth of an array?

Tags: php

I have a two dimensional array, lets call it BASE.
Now I wanto to iterate over this array with a foreach loop, and each time push the currently selected array into a new array.

```
foreach($BASE as $array){
$newarray = [];
array_push($newarray, $array);
$newarraylength = count($newarray[0])
//some more code 
}
```

This way, I want to accomplish being able to iterate over the pushed array inside a for-loop nested inside this foreach loop, like this

```
for(index = 0; index < $newarraylength; $index++){
newarray[0][index]
}
```

However, when the array from the BASE array is pushed into the new array, this new array for some reason becomes threedimensional Oo
Therefore, the syntax above doesn't work.

So, either someone of you please tell me how to deal with looping through this threedimensional array. Because my head doesn't manage to find a solution to this.
Or someone please tell me how to push a 1-dimensional array into another 1-dimensional, still empty array, without creating a 3-dimensional array.

Comment: You're pushing $BASE not $array...

Comment: If you just want to copy an array, you don't need a loop. `$newarray = $BASE;` should work fine. If you need to reset the keys, you can use `array_values`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is:

```
foreach($BASE as $array){
    $newarray = [];
    array_push($newarray, $array);
    $newarraylength = count($newarray[0])
    //some more code 
}
```

What you've done is to push the whole two dimensional array. 
So if $BASE is:

```
array(
   '1' => array('a', 'b'),
   '2' => array('c', 'd')
)
```

Then pushing that to $newarray would result in

```
$newarray = 
array(
  0 => array(
     '1' => array('a', 'b'),
     '2' => array('c', 'd')
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are basically trying to achieve is:

```
foreach($BASE as $array){
    $newarray = [];
    array_push($newarray, $array);
    $newarraylength = count($newarray[0])
    //some more code 
    for(index = 0; index < $newarraylength; $index++){
          //your code with newarray[0][index] here
    }
}
```

but could use two nested foreach

```
foreach($BASE as $array){

    foreach($array as $key=>$value){

    }
}
```

keep in mind that the first method will only work with non associative array...